# Can't install VS 2013 due to need newer operating system

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to download and install VS 2013 from MSDN subscription today and I am getting an error message that states:"This version of Visual Studio requires a computer with a newer operating system."

I checked the requirements and it claims that it can be used with Windows 7SP1 and IE10 which is what I have. I have ever updated my Typescript install as suggested by a Google search.

Does anyone know if you can install the MSDN version with Windows 7? Or is there anything else that I might need to install to get 2013 to install on my machine?

Comment: Are you getting the error when clicking the download link or when trying to install from the ISO which has already been successfully downloaded?  Or are you using the web install?

Comment: I am using the web install. I click it and then a visual studio dialog appears (the stylized version) with the message in a textblock inside of it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, also while trying to install through ISO.
My Windows OS also doesn't show which Service Pack it's running on, may be because I had used Windows Loader.
Is there a way I can get through?